# How do I perform Java HTTP GET call in Android and WAIT for a response?

Tags: java, android, http

I will try to make this a simple as possible (which is more than I can say for the Java HTTP setups I have seen).

I have a decision tree (pseudo) within my Activity:

```
private void okOnClick(View v){
   if(HttpService.isCredentialValid()){
     //wait to do something
   } else {
     //wait to do something else
   }
}
```

Then I have an HttpService:

```
public class HttpService {
   public static boolean isCredentialValid(){
     //GET `http://my_server:8080/is-valid?someParam=123`
     //the endpoint will return a 200 or 500
   }
}
```

I don't want `isCredentialValid` to do any actions to the UI, I just want it to tell me, true or false.

I don't want to tightly couple it to a `button.setText()` or any of that, I just want a simple contract `response.code == 200`

In nearly every language this is not that difficult. Can someone please set me straight here.

...Sorry for any sounds of hostility. This is one of the most elementary mechanics of nearly every codebase I have ever worked with. And I am only finding Asynchronous patterns that have no way to return something substantial to the method caller. Or I am finding methods that endanger the main thread with no way to catch errors (when there is no connection for instance).

---

So far I have tried something like below (adjusted the code for simplification). I have allowed this to operate on the main thread, because I do want it to synchronously block. However there is no way to catch on the scenario for bad internet connection or when the remote server does not respond:

```
 public static boolean isCredentialValid(){
    String url = "http://my_server:8080?param=123";
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new 
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    try {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();


        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.code() == 200;
    } catch(Exception e){ 
        // 
        //THIS DOES NOT GET HIT WHEN THERE 
        //IS A BAD CONNECTION OR REMOTE SERVER FAILS TO RESPOND
        //the app just hangs then quits
        //
        Log.d("ERROR:", e.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting up a Boolean variable based on it value you can perform your desired action ?

Comment: Just curious, what have you worked with?

Comment: Updating in the original question now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't execute your request on the main thread. Also, on Android HTTP requests are meant to be executed asynchronously, it's an extremely bad practice and a code smell if you need to execute them synchronously as a return for a method. The proper way of doing what you are trying to achieve is through the usage of the callback pattern. Your method shouldn't return anything, but invoke a callback which should be received as one of its parameters. If you still have the extreme necessity of doing things synchronously because either you don't know how to handle asynchronous calls or your architecture doesn't allow it, how about using a `CountDownLatch`? Excuse my Kotlin, but basically it works like this:

```
val countDownLatch = CountDownLatch(1)

// Execute your request

countDownLatch.countDown()

try {
    countDownLatch.await(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Give it a 30 seconds timeout
    // return the response code here.
} catch (ex: InterruptedException) {
    // Catch the timeout exception
}
```

Anyway, you should probably re-think about the necessity of actually returning from that method in particular instead of using callbacks, what I proposed isn't exactly the best practice.

PS: This code below is REALLY a bad idea. Basically what you are doing is forcing Android to allow HTTP requests on the main thread, which will completely block the UI of your application.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: Of course that is understood, finding that code comes with tons of warnings. However, my hope was that there was a safe way to execute linearly (blocking the main thread) for a pure transaction. If a proper timeout and try catch existed (meaning all scenarios were covered, which it seems is not), then blocking the main thread is a reasonable thing to do in certain circumstances.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I think your thinking is entirely valid, and covers a much more common scenario for app developers. I will accept the answer, as in 99.9% of scenarios it is the correct one.

Comment: Blocking the main thread isn't generally a good idea. There are other ways to avoid blocking the main thread yet be able to remain in full control of the whole situation. If there's a need for synchronicity the callback pattern provides that without blocking the UI of your app or risking an ANR. I know you might need to refactor some parts of your app, but give it a shot, maybe you'll find it to be the solution you are looking for :)